# How would you count the times two nodes in an XML file occur in one element?

Tags: php, xml, dom

Say I have several XML files of persons and the books they have written, like so:

```
<person name="Margret Jane" id="mj"> 
  <book>
    <author id="mj"> Margret Jane </author> 
    <author id="js"> Sarah Jane </author>
    <author id="ms"> Michael Scott </author>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author id="mj"> Margret Jane </author> 
    <author id="fr"> Freya Rob </author>
    <author id="ms"> Michael Scott </author>
  </book>
```

etc etc

How would I be able to count the times Margret and Michael were co-authors.

I have used this:

```
$getMargret = new DOMDocument();
$getMargret->load("Margret.xml");

$counter= $getMargret->getElementsByTagName("person")[0]->getElementsByTagName('book')->length;

print_r($counter);
```

in order to get the total books Margret has authored herself, but I am unsure of how to count instances of co-authorship.

Comment: I believe XPath might work, but i'm not sure how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [DOMXpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) checking for both names:

```
/person/book[author = ' Margret Jane ' and author = ' Michael Scott ']
```

*Code example*

```
$getMargret = new DOMDocument();
$getMargret->load("Margret.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($getMargret);
$counter=  $xpath->query("/person/book[author = ' Margret Jane ' and author = ' Michael Scott ']")->length;
echo $counter;
```

*Output*

```
2
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/927re)